# Namespaced keyword makes spec for JSON invalid

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I am using Clojure.spec to validate the structure of JSON (and later conform it into another format):

```
(s/def ::yes string?)
(s/def ::my-test (s/keys :req [::yes]))

(def my-json (json/read-json "{\"yes\": \"yes\"}")) ; => {:yes "yes"}

(s/valid? ::my-test my-json)       ; => false
(s/valid? ::my-test {::yes "yes"}) ; => true

(s/explain ::my-test {:yes "yes"})
; => val: {:yes "yes"} fails spec: :spec.core/my-test predicate: 
;         (contains? % :spec.core/yes)
```

(Here `s` refers to the `clojure.spec` namespace and `json` to `clojure.data.json`.)

As can be seen above the `s/valid?` fails for the parsed JSON because the keywords are not namespaced.

How can I adjust the code so that the JSON is seen as valid?

Comment: You could use `:req-un` instead of `:req`, but it will break the second case unless you change it to `{:yes "yes"}`.

Comment: @kongeor thanks. Is that an idiomatic approach? I found another way to have the namespace attached: map over the keys with `#(keyword (str "my.namespace/" (clojure.string/replace (str %) ":" "")))`. That is worse I think :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following which will work:

```
(def my-json (json/read-str "{\"yes\": \"yes\"}" :key-fn #(keyword (str *ns*) %)))
```

I'm not sure if this is the right/idiomatic way to handle it - I guess it depends on the case.

Comment: Thank  you. Using `un-req` seems to ignore the defined specs (only looks at the key I suppose). Your solution does use the specs defined earlier! For now I use it.